# How to integrate java web application in Ingram Micro marketplace

Tags: cloud, aps

I have an product written in java it is cloud related product i need to publish my application in Ingram micro marketplace ?
I need a sample how to integrate java application in market place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this website http://doc.apsstandard.org/7.1/

There, there is all the needed info to develop an APS package to integrate your cloud application into the OA platform.

To add your product to Ingram Micro Cloud Marketplace you will need to contact to them: http://www.ingrammicrocloud.com/contact-us/

Comment: Thanks for that Help

Comment: Sorry for late response i already finished my Product integration with Ingram Micro Marketplace they provided the sample how to make it that the link is: https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.aps.odin.com%2Feditor%2Fapi%2Fblueprint&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGZFuJaddrWCXDIiJNyWHyjr6-D2g

Answer (score 0):

Ingram Micro Cloud Marketplace uses Odin Automation as an underlying ordering & subscription management platform.

You can read more about the platform and the way to integrate your service with it in this tutorial: https://help.aps.odin.com/tutorial.

You can also shuffle through this YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/c/apsteam for a brief overview of the underlying technology and integration process.